# Transformation in Mathematica (Dilation, Reflection, Translation)

Tags: coordinate-transformation

Is there a Mathematica command which allows us to do various translations on a function (dilation, reflection, translation)?

For example, consider `f[x_] = x^3`. Hoe would I dilate it by a factor of 2 from the x-axis, reflect it in the x-axis and translate it of 4 units up (positive in the y axis) to get a transformed cubic graph.

Note for the OP : quadratic deliberately replaced by cubic because quadratic is symetric and hence the reflection has no effect)

Comment: Have you seen `TranslationTransform`, `ReflectionTransform`, `ScalingTransform`, `AffinetTransform` etc.?

Comment: Nope not yet. Is that the primary commands for translations?

Comment: @KrishivSURESH as suggested in Andre’s comment, it’s difficult to tell from the question what it is that you need. Could you give an example of a function and an operation of the type that you want on that operation?

Comment: Oh sorry. I meant a basic function equation like for example,  f[x] = x^2. Then we would have to dilate this a factor of 2 from the x-axis, reflection in the x-axis and a translation of 4 units up (positive in the y axis). By applying all these translations, we would get a translated quadratic graph.

Comment: @andre314 The question has been reopened. Perhaps you could post your approach as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can think the problem as a composition of functions :

```
f[x_] = x^3;
g = RightComposition[2 # &, -# &, f, # + 4 &];
Plot[g[x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 10}}]
```

[image]

I have used pure functions (`#... &`).
If you don't want to use pure functions :

```
myDilation[x_] := 2 x;
myReflection[x_] := -x;
myTranslation[x_] := x + 4;
g02[x_] := myTranslation[f[myReflection[myDilation[x]]]];
Plot[g02[x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 10}}]
```

Or :

```
g03=RightComposition[myDilation,myReflection, f, myTranslation];
Plot[g03[x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0, 10}}]
```